Issue with Flutter AppsFlyer SDK integration: ADClientErrorTrackingRestrictedOrDenied
I am integrating the sdk in my flutter project to work with an android and iOS apps, for android I didn’t find yet any issue on doing it. However, for iOS it’s necessary an additional step for displaying to users apple’s tracking authorization dialog for iOS 14+. My issue is that AppsFlyer SDK is not reading correctly this authorization status, the SDK is initialized always with this status as “not determined” or “denied”. So my tracked data is not appearing in AppsFlyer dashboard because of this issue, so here are the correct flow (what should happen) and the flow I am having (what is happening on my ending) detailed:
Happy flow (what should happen):

Open app.
Display Apple’s tracking authorization.
Accept tracking.
AppsFlyer SDK initialize with tracking status as: 2 - “authorized”.
AppsFlyer SDK send events with no errors, and data be reflected on Dashboard correctly.

Current flow with the issue:

Open app.
Display apple’s tracking authorization.
Accept tracking.
AppsFlyer SDK initialize with tracking status as: 0 - “notDetermined” or 3 - “denied".
AppsFlyer SDK send events with errors, and data is not reflected on Dashboard (since for the SDK, user’s apparently did not authorize tracking).

Here you can find a personal fork of your example project with the code for displaying apple’s tracking authorization dialog: https://github.com/Themakew/appsflyer-flutter-plugin. What I did was basically setup the project to run the iOS app and add all necessary code to display tracking’s alert.
What is happening on my end:
After step 2, I can in the Xcode console log from AppsFlyer SDK that shows that is considering tracking status as “0” and later “3”:
[com.appsflyer.serial] [ATT] Tracking authorization update from `oldStatus`: -255 to `newStatus`: 0

[com.appsflyer.serial] [ATT] Tracking authorization update from `oldStatus`: 0 to `newStatus`: 3

And in VSCode flutter logs, ATT status is:
[log] ATT status: TrackingStatus.authorized

After step 3, logs shows that when SDK is sending a API request, payload is considering as well ATT status as denied or not determined (which is an error):
"af_iad_data":{"error":"ADClientErrorTrackingRestrictedOrDenied"}

After step 4, logs shows that SDK is sending the purchase event and in its payload is appearing again the error:
"af_iad_data":{"error":"ADClientErrorTrackingRestrictedOrDenied"}

Even if I restart the app over and over again, AppsFlyer SDK will never update the ATT status on its end (even with ATT status as “authorized”). So it’s not only an issue on first app run, but after that too, when the app will be open countless times after with AppsFlyer SDK setting ATT status wrongly.
Question is: am I doing something wrong on my end or is it possibly a bug on Appsflyer, since it's not recognizing current ATT status input correctly?
